# MySQL query too long to execute

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have one query that work pretty well:

```
SELECT [MANY THINGS] 
FROM vehicule v0_ FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY) 
INNER JOIN categorie_vehicule c1_ ON v0_.idCategorieVehicule = c1_.idCategorieVehicule 
INNER JOIN energie e2_ ON v0_.idEnergie = e2_.idEnergie 
LEFT JOIN vehicule_lastrdv v6_ ON (v6_.idVehicule = v0_.idVehicule) 
LEFT JOIN client c4_ ON v0_.idUtilisateur = c4_.idUtilisateur 
LEFT JOIN utilisateur u5_ ON c4_.idUtilisateur = u5_.idUtilisateur 
LEFT JOIN _client_has_groupe_etablissement t3_ ON c4_.idUtilisateur = t3_.idUtilisateur 
LEFT JOIN groupe_etablissement g7_ ON t3_.idGroupeEtablissement = g7_.idGroupeEtablissement 
WHERE v0_.actifVehicule = 1 AND 
(v0_.pseudo LIKE '%ae%' 
OR c1_.abrevCategorieVehicule LIKE '%ae%' 
OR v0_.immatriculation LIKE '%ae%' 
OR v0_.marque LIKE '%ae%' 
OR v0_.modele LIKE '%ae%' 
OR v0_.dateProchainControle LIKE '%ae%' OR t3_.codeClient LIKE '%ae%' 
OR c4_.nomSociete LIKE '%ae%' 
OR u5_.prenomUtilisateur LIKE '%ae%' 
OR u5_.nomUtilisateur LIKE '%ae%' 
OR u5_.telUtilisateur LIKE '%ae%' 
OR u5_.mobileUtilisateur LIKE '%ae%' 
OR v6_.maxDateRDV LIKE '%ae%' 
OR v6_.villeEtablissement LIKE '%ae%' 
OR e2_.libEnergie LIKE '%ae%')  
ORDER BY v0_.idVehicule DESC LIMIT 207 OFFSET 0
```

With 800 000 vehicules, 600 000 clients and utilisateurs I've got a result in 1 second.
But I want the number total of results and I don't know how to did it fast (I can have 800 000 results).
I tried with a COUNT instead of all the select list but it takes 20s. I use doctrine and try with Paginator (because of the limit in the clause) but same result (20s).
I also tried with `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` but same thing

Have you got an idea to have the number of rows very fast ?

Thanks a lot

EDIT : 
The EXPLAIN for the first query :

```
id  select_type table partitions type possible_keys key key_len ref rows filtered Extra
1   PRIMARY v0_     ref IDX_D0599D4B9F7AC00B,IDX_D0599D4B323EB152,idx_vehicule_actifVehicule    idx_vehicule_actifVehicule  1   const   440436  100.00  Using where
1   PRIMARY e2_     eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   r4-p19d.v0_.idEnergie   1   100.00  
1   PRIMARY c1_     eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   r4-p19d.v0_.idCategorieVehicule 1   100.00  
1   PRIMARY <derived2>      ref <auto_key0> <auto_key0> 5   r4-p19d.v0_.idVehicule  10  100.00  
1   PRIMARY c4_     eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   r4-p19d.v0_.idUtilisateur   1   100.00  
1   PRIMARY u5_     eq_ref  PRIMARY,idx_utilisateur_idUtilisateur_actifUtilisateur_mailUtilisateur  PRIMARY 4   r4-p19d.c4_.idUtilisateur   1   100.00  
1   PRIMARY t3_     ref PRIMARY,IDX_30B01ADE5D419CCB    IDX_30B01ADE5D419CCB    4   r4-p19d.c4_.idUtilisateur   1   100.00  
1   PRIMARY g7_     eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   r4-p19d.t3_.idGroupeEtablissement   1   100.00  Using index
2   DERIVED rdv     index   PRIMARY,IDX_86645D0C4FFC60ED,idx_rdv_idRDV_dateRDV_idAgenda idx_rdv_idRDV_dateRDV_idAgenda  17      981942  33.33   Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DERIVED agenda      eq_ref  PRIMARY,IDX_2B41CD41EA190502    PRIMARY 4   r4-p19d.rdv.idAgenda    1   100.00  Using where
2   DERIVED etablissement       eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   r4-p19d.agenda.idEtablissement  1   100.00  
2   DERIVED _vehicule_has_controle      ref IDX_1EAA071A9F61066B    IDX_1EAA071A9F61066B    5   r4-p19d.rdv.idRDV   1   100.00
```

And for the COUNT :

```
id  select_type table partitions type possible_keys key key_len ref rows filtered Extra
1   PRIMARY v0_     ref IDX_D0599D4B9F7AC00B,IDX_D0599D4B323EB152,idx_vehicule_actifVehicule    idx_vehicule_actifVehicule  1   const   440436  100.00  Using where
1   PRIMARY e2_     eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   r4-p19d.v0_.idEnergie   1   100.00  Using index
1   PRIMARY c1_     eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   r4-p19d.v0_.idCategorieVehicule 1   100.00  Using index
1   PRIMARY <derived2>      ref <auto_key0> <auto_key0> 5   r4-p19d.v0_.idVehicule  10  100.00  
1   PRIMARY c4_     eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   r4-p19d.v0_.idUtilisateur   1   100.00  Using index
1   PRIMARY u5_     eq_ref  PRIMARY,idx_utilisateur_idUtilisateur_actifUtilisateur_mailUtilisateur  PRIMARY 4   r4-p19d.c4_.idUtilisateur   1   100.00  Using index
1   PRIMARY t3_     ref PRIMARY,IDX_30B01ADE5D419CCB    PRIMARY 4   r4-p19d.c4_.idUtilisateur   1   100.00  Using index
1   PRIMARY g7_     eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   r4-p19d.t3_.idGroupeEtablissement   1   100.00  Using index
2   DERIVED rdv     index   PRIMARY,IDX_86645D0C4FFC60ED,idx_rdv_idRDV_dateRDV_idAgenda idx_rdv_idRDV_dateRDV_idAgenda  17      981941  33.33   Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DERIVED agenda      eq_ref  PRIMARY,IDX_2B41CD41EA190502    PRIMARY 4   r4-p19d.rdv.idAgenda    1   100.00  Using where
2   DERIVED etablissement       eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   r4-p19d.agenda.idEtablissement  1   100.00  
2   DERIVED _vehicule_has_controle      ref IDX_1EAA071A9F61066B    IDX_1EAA071A9F61066B    5   r4-p19d.rdv.idRDV   1   100.00
```

Comment: `vehicule_lastrdv` is a view?

Comment: @jkavalik Yes it is. But if a remove it from the query, it doesn't change the execution time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Abandon all hope!**

First, there is a contradiction...  You say `FORCE INDEX(PRIMARY)`, yet `PRIMARY` is not an option; instead the better `(actifVehicule)` is being used.  *Please* provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is difficult to guess at what indexes you have.

**Here's what is going on...**

1. It is starting with V0 and and filtering on `actifVehicule=1`.
2. Since (I assume you are using InnoDB), that index is really `(actifVehicule, idVehicule)`, it can now avoid the "filesort" for the `ORDER BY` and scan directly through that index.  Note:  This (and only this) allows it to stop after `LIMIT 207` matching rows.
3. *Apparently*, most rows match `pseudo LIKE '%ae%'`, so it finds 207 matches before having to scan too far.  This would explain why the `SELECT` is faster than the `COUNT`.

For the `COUNT(*)` (which you have not shown; I am *guessing* that it starts `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...`), the *entire* set needs to be scanned.  That includes all 800K rows of v0.  Well, actually less than that because some don't satisfy `actifVehicule=1`; let's take the `EXPLAIN's` number of 440K.  Plus, for each of those 440K rows, it must reach into the many tables that are `OR'd` together and check for `%ae%`.  That adds up to about 9*440K random probes.

I'd say MySQL is pretty fast to take only 20 seconds to look at 4M rows scattered all over.  You probably had a buffer_pool big enough to cache it all. It might have taken hours if it had been I/O bound.

`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` has to do both things -- find 207 rows *and* do the entire `COUNT`.

**How to speed it up?**

Plan A:  Abandon "just enter a string, I'll find it anywhere"... Change the UI to require the user to say which field to search.  Then have the correct indexes so that you can go *from* the searched field *back to* the Vehicle.

Plan B:  Lump all the strings into *one* field in a new table, have the vehicleId in that same table; then start by searching that table.  Oh, maintain that table so that it includes *only* 'active' vehicles.  Then it is a scan of 440K rows, not 4M.  So, the `COUNT` *might* be 10 times as fast.  (And the regular `SELECT` will be somewhat faster.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will take the first plan cause it's the end of the project and I have no time to make the plan B. But for the future I will implement this solution. Thanks a lot :)